# why does the component render 3 times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a component like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  console.log("comp run");

  const tick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log(count);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(tick, 10000);
    console.log("effect run");

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log("clear func run");
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>{count}</div>;
}

export default Counter;
```

When the code runs, the console outputs as follows:

Output immediately when the program runs:

---

> comp run
>
> effect run

---

after 10 seconds :

---

> comp run
>
> 0

---

after 10 seconds :

---

> comp run
>
> 0

---

after 10 seconds :

---

> 0 (then it keeps increasing by 0 every ten seconds)

---

What I don't understand here is exactly this: "comp run" is printed on the screen 3 times. Why 3 ?

Comment: because every 10 seconds you're updating count, which rerenders your component

Comment: Actually it looks like you're not updating count since it's always 0.

Comment: You may also want to think about using something like `useInterval` [as using `setInterval` with an effect can have odd side-effects](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).

Comment: Try to switch the ```setCount(count + 1);``` to ```setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);```

Answer (score 1):

This is because [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) memoize all values inside it. You can use two ways:

1. Add `count` to useEffect's dependencies array. And when count changes, useEffect will refreshed.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       //Your old code here
   }, [count]); //Here
   ```

2. Create a function inside of [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook and memoize function for better performance. Works like in first way, but dependent by tick fucntion, wich dependent by count state.

   ```
   const tick = useCallback(() => {
     setCount(count + 1);
     console.log(count);
   }, [count]);

   useEffect(() => {
     const timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
     console.log("effect run");

     return () => {
       clearInterval(timer);
       console.log("clear func run");
     };
   }, [tick]);
   ```